# Predicate inner components in sentence (object without determiner)

Tags: grammar, determiners, objects

I'm working on a computer program that might output the following sentence:

> Analyst Mark Mahaney upgraded rating on Apple to Buy

Is that sentence valid in English? (That is, nothing betwen the action `upgraded` and the word `rating`)

Comment: More formally, "Analyst Mark Mahaney has upgraded the rating on Apple to 'Buy'." I assume your readers would know the context here; whether or not you use the terser format is largely a matter of personal preferences - yours and your readership's. I could imagine that some laypersons could soon get confused without more conventional formatting (and an explanation of what this 'Apple rating' is).

Comment: Shouldn't it be *rating **of** Apple*? I first read it as meaning that the rating is stored **on** an Apple (computer) and wondered why that was significant.

Comment: It seems like perfectly good Headlinese English, if that is your goal.

Comment: _Analyst Mark Mahaney_ is awfully reminiscent of Dan Brown's awful writing style. That's a very odd way to begin an English sentence; one doesn't normally identify people's occupation by apposition, at least in normal conversation. Is the problem that you don't wanna hafta generate a gendered possessive (_his, her,_ or _their_)? If so, it's just one more tag to keep on the analyst's database entry; you gotta have one anyway.

Comment: @MEd: I don't know, I would really use the present tense in a headline like this?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. @JohnLawler We do NLP, none of the data is entered manually into the database, otherwise we'd use 'his' or 'her'. Currently, we're just trying to figure out if that sentence is valid English or not. I'm also open to suggestions on phrasing but was worried it would be off topic here.

Comment: @TrevorD, In the context of analyst ratings on equities, _on_ is indeed a common, probably the standard, preposition. Contrast "Rumplestiltskin Analysts commenced coverage of Apple with a rating of Neutral".

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why?

Comment: @ Benjamin: If you could change your program so it output *Analyst Mark Mahaney upgraded **Apple rating** to Buy*, this issue simply wouldn't arise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a case where you would properly use [zero determiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners#Zero_determiner). That said, while your example sentence ignores the general rule for using a determiner, it does not strike me as wrong so much as terse. It sounds like it's on the continuum with [Telegram style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style). I would expect to see a sentence such as yours in a place where space is at a premium, such as in a headline or summary. It would be out of place in an essay or long article. In such a context, I would expect the following:

> **The** analyst Mark Mahaney upgraded **his** rating **of** Apple to "buy."

As Zack points out, if using a gendered word such as "his" is giving you heartburn, you can say "their," which is quickly becoming the gender-neutral way to say "his/her."

I'm not completely clear on the context in which your sentence will be read, but perhaps one of the following formats could be as easily produced:

> The rating of Apple has been upgraded to "buy" by the analyst Mark
>   Mahaney.

or

> Apple has received a "buy" rating upgrade from the analyst Mark
>   Mahaney.

I recognize that these are passive rather than active, but the preference for active voice should not be treated as an inviolable law.

By the way, "grammatically correct" does not equal good. See [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).

Comment: We don't know the gender of the analyst. This is because we read  these articles using natural language processing algorithms. These are sent via email so space is ok.

Comment: Right. So, that's why I suggested two alternative constructions that don't use the analyst's gender. "The rating of [company] has been [upgraded/downgraded/changed] to [rating] by the [role] [name]."

Comment: Or “Analyst Mark Mahaney upgraded their rating of Apple to ‘buy.’ ”  Singular *they* / *their* is perfectly cromulent in general, and by me is no less unexceptionable when used with a personal name antecedent, although in that particular case [reasonable people may disagree](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2600).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I'd upvote but I spent all my reputation on the bounty.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum, I appreciate it. The bounty is plenty. :-)